# Android lollipop listview ending effect change color

Tags: java, android, android-5.0-lollipop

How can i put and have this effect (the color of ending effects) that used in Android 5?

Which code should I use, and what's this name?

[image]

Comment: **sorry i don't know the name**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's called the `colorEdgeEffect`.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light">
    <item name="android:colorEdgeEffect">#7b0</item>
</style>
```